# Разложить число на простые множители

Tags: python, факторизация

Как в питоне разложить число на множители, чтобы их произведение было равно этому числу.

```
number=int(input("Integer: "))
for i in range(1, number+1):
    if(number%i==0):
        print(i)
```

При вводе числа (например) 63. На выходе получается:

```
1
3
7
9
21
63
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
n=int(input("Integer: ")) 
factors = []
d = 2
while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n//=d
        else:
            d += 1
        if n > 1:
            factors.append(n)
        else:
            break
print('{} = {}' .format(n,factors))
```

На выходе получется: 7 = [63, 3, 21, 3, 7]

---

А мне необходимо получить:
63 = 3 * 3 * 7

Comment: Ну так у вас number в цикле не меняется...

Comment: Простите за нескромный вопрос, но зачем вы делаете factors.append(n)?

Comment: `factors.append(n)` лишнее, достаточно `if n = 1: break`

Comment: @Akina вместо factors.append(n) поставить break - фигня получается

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов А изменение оператора сравнения не проглядели?

Comment: @Akina проглядел, точно :-D

Comment: Да и для `while` никакого условия не нужно, т.е. просто `while true` (ну или `do`, если такое есть в питоне). Иначе этот код на обычную тройку ничего не выведет...

Comment: Благодарю, товарищи! Почти получилось. Как теперь только из 63 = [3, 3, 7] преобразовать в 63 = 3 *3 * 7. Не судите строго, только учусь.

Comment: @Grigorij 1- у вас нет лишнего кода, у вас отступ неправильный. Отступы важны в Питоне. Посмотрите на код внизу: какой отступ у if n > 1:...` (это выводит его ща пределы цикла). 2- если не знаете как преобразовать [3,3,7] в 3*3*7, то разбейте на более простые шаги: как целое число в строку превратить, как это сделать для списка чисел, как объединить эти строки звёздочкой: `" * ".join(map(int, [3,3,7]))`

Answer (score 7):

Эта задача называется [Факторизация целых чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)

Одна из реализаций(взято с [OEIS#A238724](https://oeis.org/A238714)):

```
def primfacs(n):
   i = 2
   primfac = []
   while i * i <= n:
       while n % i == 0:
           primfac.append(i)
           n = n / i
       i = i + 1
   if n > 1:
       primfac.append(n)
   return primfac
```

Comment: [похожий код из ответа @Daniel Fischer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16996439/4279)

Answer (score 3):

В коде есть два существенных момента, из-за которых он ищет все делители вместо факторизации. Добавлю ещё одно изменение ради оптимизации и получится такой код:

http://ideone.com/qi60fH

```
import math

number=int(input())

for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1): # обычно делитель не будет больше корня
    while (number % i == 0): # while, а не if
        print(i)
        number //= i # убираем множитель из числа

if (number != 1): # но один делитель может быть больше корня
    print (number)
```

PS: Но вообще вариант с циклом из соседнего ответа лучше.

Comment: "случай, что само число было простым" В number всегда будет последний простой делитель(кроме случая, когда на входе была единица).

Comment: @vp_arth, нет, во всех остальных случаях там 1. Мы же делим на каждый простой делитель до корня, пока они не кончатся.

Comment: ок, не всегда, иногда там 1. Однако, `51 => range(2, 8) => 3, 17!`

Comment: @vp_arth, да, понял. Поменял комментарий. Если хочешь, можешь ещё сам поправить что-нибудь. Но код-то верный во втором варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, например, как сделано [здесь](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Существуют более сложные и [эффективные методы](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/factorization). А также обратите внимание на [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) ([тут](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/eratosthenes_sieve)). Если вы хотите получать факторизацию не для одного числа, а для большого набора числел, то выгоднее использовать перебор по простым. Об этом я расскажу чуть ниже.

Кроме того, я думаю, что Вы имели ввиду, что хотите разложить число на простые множители, ведь так? Я сужу по Вашему замечанию, насчёт правильного ответа:

```
7 = [63, 3, 21, 3, 7] А должно: 63 = 3 * 3 * 7
```

Хотя, строки:

```
if n > 1:
   factors.append(n)
else:
   break
```

говорят о том, что Вы пытаетесь искать все делители.

В таком случае, нужно писать правильно заголовок вопроса, чтобы не смущать людей.

Насчёт Вашего решения. Я не понимаю, зачем Вы добавляете в итоговый список текущий делитель. Это неверно, так как добавлять в итоговый список следует лишь простые числа, а текущий делитель, очевидно, не простой. Так что строки:

```
if n > 1:
   factors.append(n)
else:
   break
```

лишние.

Для того, чтобы получить все делители, вам нужно слегка модифицировать Ваш алгоритм:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

n = int(input("Integer: "))
factors = []
d = 2
m = n # Запомним исходное число
while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n//=d
        else:
            d += 1
factors.append(n) # Добавим последнеё простое число
print('{} = {}' .format(m, factors)) # Выводим исходное число и все простые множители.
```

Теперь о предподсчёте с простыми числами. Легко понять, что коль скоро мы знаем все простые числа, то выгоднее не перебирать те элементы, которые являются сами по себе произведением простых. Т.е. будем перебирать только числа:

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 ...
```

Числа же:

```
4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12 ...
```

оставим в покое, так как они являются произведением простых. Для этого, с помощью решета Эратосфена вычислим заранее все простые до некоторого предела (`2 ^ 64`). После этого полученное со входной строки число для факторизации будем раскладывать по простым следующим образом. Делим число `n` до тех пор, пока оно делится на `i`-ое простое. Все простые будем записывать в `factors`. Как только число перестаёт делиться на `i`-ое, берём `i+1`-ое число. И так до тех пор, пока `n != 1`.

Спешу заметить, что хранение простых чисел, разумеется, является затратным. НО! Для большинства задач очень подходит, так как не требуется вычислять простые числа свыше `100000000`. Оперативная память современных ПК более чем позволяет хранить `1ГБ` и более данных. Простых чисел оказывается не слишком много. Согласно [одной довольно известной теореме о простых числах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB), их оказывается порядка `n/ln(n)` при возрастании `n`. Это означает, что для `100000000` их будет примерно `5,3 млн`, что является вполне себе допустимым. Более того, даже `1 млрд.` чисел выдержит среднестатистический ПК, так как простых числе окажется не более `50 млн`. А значит, для памяти это будет `50 млн`. `4-байтовых` чиселок, т.е. `200000000 байт`. В мегабайтах это всего лишь `200`. Так что большой проблемы в хранении нет.

Comment: Объясните, за что меня минусуют?

Comment: Возможно минус был за приписку, которая была убрана во второй редакции

Comment: Кроме того, мне непонятно, почему заплюсовали ответ, в котром приведён практически один код.

Comment: Я думаю, про это пояснили в ответе на твой вопрос на мете :-)

Comment: по поводу: `if n>1: factors.append(n)` -- это просто автор скопировал код неправильно: отступы нарушены. С правильным отступом эта конструкция вне цикла находится¶ А у вас код считает `1` простым числом (что неправильно).

Answer (score 0):

```
def factors(num, d=2):
    while num > 1:
        n1, n2 = divmod(num, d)
        if n2:
            d += 1
        else:
            yield d
            num = n1

n = int(input("Integer: "))
print('{} = {}' .format(n, ' * '.join(map(str, factors(n)))))

>>> Integer: 63
>>> 63 = 3 * 3 * 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input())
list_simple = []
simple = 2
while num > 1:
    if num % simple == 0:
        list_simple.append(simple)
        num = num/simple
    else:
        simple += 1
print(list_simple)
```