# Как разложить число на множители всеми возможными способами

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def divide(n):
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        if n%d == 0:
            print (n, '*')
            divide(n//d)
        d = d+1
    if n>1:
        print(n)
        print('____')
n = input(n)
n = int(n)
divide(n)
```

У меня получилось вот это, но оно не работает так, как надо

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разложить число на простые множители](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645227/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def divide(n):
    d = 2
    flag = False
    while d*d <= n:
        if n%d == 0:
            print (d, '*', end=" ")
            divide(n//d)
            flag = True
        d += 1
    
    if not flag:
        print(n)

n = int(input())

divide(n)
```

Comment: Спасибо, это убрало все неправильные варианты

Answer (score 1):

Есть пара идей, в код пока не особо получается преобразовать:

Сначала разложим число на простые множители, а потом уже будем их друг на друга комбинациями умножать

Код для нахождения простых делителей:

```
n=0 #сброс (необязательно)
n =int(input(n))
s_divs=[] #массив простых делителей
def s_div(n): #функция нахождения всех простых делителей n
    a = [] #массив простых делителей
    d = [] #массив всех 'претендентов'
    #перебираем делители
    for i in range(n-2): #от 2 до n-1 включительно
        d.append(i+2)
    for i_2 in range(len(d)): #кол-во претендентов
        if n % d[i_2] == 0: #остаток от деления равен нулю
            a.append(d[i_2])
    print('Простые делители', n, ':', a)

s_divs=s_div(n)
```

Это плохая идея использовать саму процедуру внутри себя, работает некорректно